# How is my robots.txt?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, robots.txt

Since I haven't ever made a robots.txt before, I am little nervous submitting one for a fully working webshop. Does anyone see anything critical in the following, or should I be able to submit it as it is? Any advice is highly appreciated!

```
# Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
#Disallow: /js/
#Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
#Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /maggie/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/
Disallow: /tilmeld-nyhedsbrev/
Disallow: /tak-for-din-tilmelding/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
Disallow: *dir=*
Disallow: *order=*
Disallow: *mode=*
Disallow: */l/*
```

Comment: A technical note: [Records may not contain empty lines](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18356/5949).

Answer (score 1):

I reckon Inchoo gives a good overview as well, with different options and examples to learn from 
   Inchoo’s recommended Magento robots.txt boilerplate:

```
# Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
#Disallow: /js/
#Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
#Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

I think thats the one you are using or? For me yours looks fine and ready to use for a webshop. I´m using similar ones across shops

Source [Click here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/)

Comment: Yes it is. I have added a little extra, but i've used that one as template.

Comment: Seems good to me and still in standard

Comment: One thing I've found is if you block access to /skin/ it can cause issues if your site is responsive, and Google's bot cannot retrieve the stylesheet for the site - it then complains about links being too close together etc